# MVC WebApi not working with Generic models

Tags: model, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, model-binding, customvalidator

I converted mij WCF WebApi project to a MVC WebApi project. I have a model with a property like this:

```
public class ObjectWaarde<T> 
{

    public ObjectWaarde(T objectType)
    {
        ObjectType = objectType;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the term to search for.
    /// </summary>
    public T ObjectType { get; set; }

    public object Waardes
    {
        get
        {

            return ObjectType;
        }
        set { ObjectType = (T) value; }
    }
}
```

When I Post this model to my ApiController this error shows up (HTTP 500):

Property accessor 'DeclaringMethod' on object 'System.RuntimeType' threw the following exception:'Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true.'

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused by the defaultbodymodelvalidator.

It's a known issue:
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/225

The only solution I found was to disable the modelvalidator.

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Clear(typeof(IBodyModelValidator));